# Determine the Dialogflow Edition

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can we determine whether we are utilizing the Trial Edition or Essentials Edition of Dialogflow?

I attempted to investigate the General section in settings but could not find any relevant information.

Could someone please provide guidance on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com -> Select your Agent -> Left Side Nav Bar you find edition info below Docs

Attaching the screenshot of left nav-bar

[image]